# Unique decomposition of a subset of complex numbers.

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

Given a set $E$, suppose that $E = F_1\cup \cdots\cup F_n$ where $F_1, \ldots, F_n$ are $n$ disjoint continua (By a continuum we mean a nonempty bounded set which is closed and connected (i.e., compact and connected)). Then the decomposition of $E$ is unique.

Suppose that $E$ has another decomposition $E = G_1\cup \cdots\cup G_m$ in terms of $m$ disjoint continua $G_1, \ldots, G_m$. Then there must be a pair of sets $G_j$ and $F_k$, where $G_j\neq F_k$, such that $H_{jk}=G_j\cap F_k\neq\emptyset$ and $I_{jk}=G_j\cap F_k^c\neq\emptyset$. It is clear that
\begin{equation*}
H_{jk}\cup I_{jk} = G_j,\ H_{jk}\cap I_{jk} = \emptyset,
\end{equation*}
and
\begin{equation*}
I_{jk}\subset \left(F_1\cup\cdots\cup F_{k-1}\cup F_{k+1}\cup\cdots\cup F_n\right).
\end{equation*}
If $\zeta$ is a limit point of $H_{jk}$, then $\zeta$ is a limit point of both $G_j$ and $F_k$, and hence $\zeta\in H_{jk}, \zeta\notin I_{jk}$. On the other hand, if $\zeta$ is a limit point of $I_{jk}$, then $\zeta$ is a limit point of some $F_l (l\neq k)$, and hence $\zeta\in F_l, \zeta\notin F_k, \zeta\notin H_{jk}$. Thus, we have found a decomposition of the connected set $G_j$ into two nonempty disjoint subsets $H_{jk}$ and $I_{jk}$, such that neither subset contain s a limit point of the other. This contradiction proves the theorem.

I don't understand the following part: Then there must be a pair of sets $G_j$ and $F_k$, where $G_j\neq F_k$, such that $H_{jk}=G_j\cap F_k\neq\emptyset$ and $I_{jk}=G_j\cap F_k^c\neq\emptyset$. Could you help me? This theorem is taken from Theory of Functions of a complex variable, A.I. Markushevich, Part I, AMS CHELSEA PUBLISHING. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since the decompositions are different there is a $G_j$ which is not an $F$; since they cover same set, there is a $F_k$ with non empty intersection with that $G_j$; but since both $F,G$ are compact and connected, neither can be strictly included in the other (the difference is not compact)

Comment: Yes, sure. I have tried to reason by contradiction, but I couldn't prove it.